# Find the N-th highest salary of employee using LINQ/Lambda

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I used sequential Linq for getting nth highest salary from employee like

```
    var ThirdHighestSal = from vr in Employee.getAllEmployee()
                 group vr by vr.Salary into gr
                 orderby gr.Key descending
                 select( new {salary=gr.OrderBy(x=>x.Salary).Skip(2).First()});
        foreach (var sal in ThirdHighestSal)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3rd highest sal is {0}",sal.salary);
        }
```

when i execute this it is throwing exception like

Sequence contains no elements(InvalidOperationException was unhadled)

Can anyone help me on that query please?

Answer (score 0):

use FirstOrDefault instead of First and you will get a null object if no element could be found.

With lamda you could write:

```
 var ThirdHighestSal = Employee.getAllEmployee().Select(x => x.Salary).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you get null or (if exists) the third highest salary.

Answer (score -2):

```
ALl: No group wise
 var employees = Employees
        .OrderByDescending(sal => sal )
        .Skip(N-1)
        .FirstOrDefault();



 
Each group wise highest salary:

var employees = Employees
        .GroupBy(e => e.Salary)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
        .Skip(N-1)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?